# SQL Error: -443, SQLState: 38111 when accessing table metadata on DB2 zOS

Tags: database, db2

I'm getting following error when using Hibernate in a Java application over my DB2 database.
This error occurs with one DB2 database and not with another (I'm almost sure the problem is in DB2 server side configuration), and I didn't found the difference between the two databases.

The SQL error -443 is missing from the documentation I found:
http:// rikipedia.co.za/index.php/DB2_SQL_Error_Codes (one link maximum per question due to reputation)

According to following link, the 111 part of the sql state 38111 would indicate the reason of the failure.
http://www.sqlerror.de/db2_sql_error_-443_sqlstate_42724.html

Any idea ?

INFO [SchemaValidator] fetching database metadata
WARN [JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL Error: -443, SQLState: 38111
ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -443, SQLSTATE: 38111, SQLERRMC: SQLTABLES;SQLTABLES;-204 MYDB.SYSTABLES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SQLCODE of [38xxx](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr/download/dsnmch12.pdf) means there was a problem with a user-defined function, stored procedure, trigger, or other external function. You won't figure this out by checking the error code.

Your best bet is to reproduce the error on a specific DB2 subsystem, assuming your company has more than one, and record the exact timestamp. Then have someone with DB2 experience examine DB2 logs to find more information.